# useImperativeHandle does not update with ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm extending Formik. Formik accepts `innerRef` as a ref to give access to the form state outside the `Formik` tree.

I also want to be able to pass a `ref` to my component and clone the Formik `innerRef` that was created inside the component:

```
import React, { createContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Formik, FormikHelpers, FormikProps, FormikValues } from 'formik';
import Controls from './Controls';
import { WizardContextData, WizardProps } from './Wizard.props';

export const WizardContext = createContext<WizardContextData>({
  previous: () => {},
  stepNumber: 0,
});

function Wizard<Values, Response extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  props: WizardProps<Values, Response> & { children: React.ReactNode },
  innerRef?: React.ForwardedRef<FormikProps<Values>>
): React.ReactElement | null {
  const {
    children,
    initialValues,
    onSubmit,
    nextButton,
    previousButton,
    controlProps,
    customControl,
    disableControls,
    stepper = null,
  } = props;

  const formRef = useRef<FormikProps<Values>>(null);

  // add ability to pass a ref by props
  React.useImperativeHandle<FormikProps<Values> | null, FormikProps<Values> | null>(innerRef, () => formRef.current);

  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState<number>(0);
  const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState<Values>(initialValues);

  const steps = React.Children.toArray(children);

  const step = steps[stepNumber];
  const totalSteps = steps.length;
  const isLastStep = stepNumber === totalSteps - 1;

  // force revalidate form on step change
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (React.isValidElement(step)) {
      if (formRef.current && step.props?.validationSchema) {
        formRef.current.validateForm();
      }
    }
  }, [step, formRef]);

  // update form state when initial values is changed
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.setValues(initialValues);
    }
  }, [initialValues]);

  const currentStepRequireIsValid = React.useMemo<boolean>(() => {
    if (React.isValidElement(step)) {
      if (step.props?.requireIsValid === undefined) {
        return true;
      }
      return !!step.props?.requireIsValid;
    }
    return false;
  }, [step]);

  const getControlsConfig = React.useCallback(
    (formik: FormikProps<Values>) => {
      if (currentStepRequireIsValid && !(formik.isValid && formik.dirty)) {
        return { disabledNextButton: true };
      }
      return {};
    },
    [currentStepRequireIsValid]
  );

  if (!React.isValidElement(step)) {
    return null;
  }

  const next = (values: Values) => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.min(stepNumber + 1, totalSteps - 1));
  };

  const previous = (values: Values) => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.max(stepNumber - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values: Values, bag: FormikHelpers<Values>): Promise<void | Response> => {
    if (step.props?.onSubmit) {
      await step.props.onSubmit(values, bag);
    }
    if (isLastStep) {
      return onSubmit(values, bag);
    } else {
      bag.setTouched({});
      next(values);
    }
  };

  const renderControls = (formik: FormikProps<Values>) => {
    // in case we want to disable the controls
    if (step.props.disableControls || disableControls) {
      return null;
    }

    if (step.props.customControl) {
      return step.props.customControl({
        previous,
        formik,
        isFormValid: formik.isValid && formik.dirty,
        stepNumber,
      });
    }
    if (customControl) {
      return customControl({
        previous,
        formik,
        isFormValid: formik.isValid && formik.dirty,
        stepNumber,
      });
    }
    return (
      <Controls
        stepNumber={stepNumber}
        formik={formik as FormikProps<any>}
        previous={previous as (values: FormikValues) => void}
        previousButton={step.props.previousButton || previousButton}
        nextButton={step.props.nextButton || nextButton}
        isLastStep={isLastStep}
        hasBackButton={controlProps?.hasBackButton}
        {...getControlsConfig(formik)}
      />
    );
  };

  const context = {
    previous,
    stepNumber,
  } as WizardContextData;

  return (
    <WizardContext.Provider value={context}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={snapshot}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={step.props?.validationSchema}
        validateOnMount={currentStepRequireIsValid}
        innerRef={formRef}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form>
            {stepper}
            {step}
            {renderControls(formik)}
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </WizardContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(Wizard) as <Values, Response extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  props: WizardProps<Values, Response> & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    innerRef?: React.ForwardedRef<FormikProps<Values>>;
  }
) => ReturnType<typeof Wizard>;
```

But whenever I pass a ref as `innerRef` to the `Wizard` component, it returns `{ current: null }` and doesn't update with the `formRef` value:

```
export const Default: Story = (args) => {
  const { onSubmit } = args;

  const ref = useRef<FormikProps<InitialValues>>(null);

  console.log(ref);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={8}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <H4>Please check the docs tab to learn how to use it</H4>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Wizard initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} innerRef={ref}>
          <WizardStep validationSchema={firstStepValidationSchema}>
            <Component1 />
          </WizardStep>
          <WizardStep validationSchema={secondStepValidationSchema}>
            <Component2 />
          </WizardStep>
        </Wizard>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

[image: log]

What's the best way to have the same `formRef` ref but optionally passing another ref as props to the `Wizard`?

In other words, I want my `Wizard` component to mimic the `innerRef` functionality from `Formik`

Comment: `React.ForwardedRef` only forwards the `ref` prop, not any other passed props, i.e. it won't forward a prop named `innerRef`. I don't know if you need to pass a `ref={ref}` prop or if you need to tweak the h`Wizard` component to reference the passed `innerRef` prop.

Comment: If I don't implement the `Wizard` with `ForwardedRef`, my `innerRef` gets the initial value of the `formRef`, but doesn't update when the `formRef` updates, even setting the dependency array with `formRef` (probably because a ref update doesn't trigger a rerender)

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: The issue was related to using a ref in `useImperativeHandle`, since refs don't trigger rerenders, the hook never updated with the new values from the `formRef`. I could solve creating a dummy component inside `Formik` that receives the `innerRef` by props and implement the `useImperativeHandle` with the `useFormikContext` hook